# Generalization of $|a^2-b^2| = |a-b||a+b|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, harmonic-analysis

Let $t, a, b>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it true that

$$|\left(t^2+a^2\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}} - \left(t^2+b^2\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}|\leq t^{\frac{n-1}{2}} |a+b|^{\frac{n+1}{2}}|a-b|^{\frac{n+1}{2}}?$$

Note that for $n=1$, this is true, since $|a^2-b^2| = |a-b||a+b|$. (This desired inequality appeared in one of my calculations in harmonic analysis.)

Does anyone know if this is true? If it is false, then what $t, a, b>0$ form a counter example?

Comment: For fixed $t, b$ and large $a$ the left-hand side is $\sim a^{n+1}$ whereas the right-hand side is $\sim t^{(n-1)/2}a^{n+1}$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! If $a\sim b$, for instance, say $c^{-1} a\leq b \leq ca$, then is there a possibility that the inequality is true? (It's probably an ill-defined question, but I want to ask anyways.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $t \leqslant 1$, and $n=2k-1,k\geqslant2$, $a \neq b$, we can assume that
$$|(t^2+a^2)^k-(t^2+b^2)^k|\leqslant t^{k-1}|a+b|^k|a-b|^k$$
$$\Rightarrow |a^{2k}-b^{2k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}{{k \choose i}t^{2i}(a^{2(k-i)}-b^{2(k-i)})}|\leqslant t^{k-1}|(a^2-b^2)^k|$$
Notice that, if $a>b$, and $n$ is positive integer$$(a-b)^n \leqslant a^n-b^n$$
$$\therefore |a^{2k}-b^{2k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}{{k \choose i}t^{2i}(a^{2(k-i)}-b^{2(k-i)})}|\leqslant t^{k-1}|a^{2k}-b^{2k}|$$
$$\Rightarrow |1+{{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{{k \choose i}t^{2i}(a^{2(k-i)}-b^{2(k-i)})}}\over{a^{2k}-b^{2k}}}|\leqslant t^{k-1}$$
But according to assumption we can easily know that $LHS>1$ and $RHS\leqslant 1$. Therefore, the inequality is not true.

Example:$t=1,a=3,b=2,n=3$